# SUMIF formula workbook name is unknown

Tags: vba, excel

I have to read to use SUMIF to check and compare the supplier number from different workbooks and if it is same then copy the Prices(using SUMIF). Everytime time the workbook can be different from which I take the prices but the sheet names and their layout will be same.So how can I write the formula in SUMIF? Can anyone help me please?
I'm stuck with this code since 2 days but couldn't figure out whats wrong.

```
    Windows(wb_name).Activate
    Range("AW18", Range("AW18").Offset(0, -44).End(xlDown).Offset(0, 44)).Formula = _
    "=SUMIF('[" & dest_name & "]" & "!" & "Cu Part PVO L",$M$10:$M$2000,C19, _
    "[" & dest_name & "]" & "Cu Part PVO L" & "'" & "!",$AD$10:$AD$2000)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have the exclamation mark in the wrong place, as well as also having too many commas.

```
   Range("AW18", Range("AW18").Offset(0, -44).End(xlDown).Offset(0, 44)).Formula = _
    "=SUMIF('[" & dest_name & "]Cu Part PVO L'!$M$10:$M$2000,C19," & _
    "'[" & dest_name & "]Cu Part PVO L'!$AD$10:$AD$2000)"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But still I'm getting #value error here :(

Comment: Then there is text in your excel file where a number should be.

Comment: Ahhh...I got the error resolved. Because just after the formula is done, I was closing the dest_name workbook and I had the formulas there so it was giving #value error. But I just clear the formulas and keep only the values and so its working perfectly. Thank u so so much. :)
I cant explain how hard it was getting after trying hundreds of solutions